# Disable Button if data-quantity is less than 1

Tags: jquery, button, custom-data-attribute

I want to disable the following button if the "data-quantity" attribute is less than 1. I can't figure out how to properly form an *if* statement to do this.

```
<button type="submit" data-product_id="1" data-product_sku="test" data-quantity="0" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</button>
```

I've tried something like this:

```
var cart_button = $('.add_to_cart_button');
if(cart_button.attr("data-quantity") < 1) {
    cart_button.prop("disabled", true);
}
```

Comment: Then your code is fine if you invoke it on `document.ready`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine! 
See working example below.

```js
var cart_button = $('.add_to_cart_button');
if(cart_button.attr("data-quantity") < 1) {
    cart_button.prop("disabled", true);
}

// Ignore code below this line, it's just for the demo

$('.set_to_1').click(function() {
  cart_button.attr("data-quantity", 1);
  if(cart_button.attr("data-quantity") < 1) {
    cart_button.prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    cart_button.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
$('.set_to_0').click(function() {
  cart_button.attr("data-quantity", 0);
  if(cart_button.attr("data-quantity") < 1) {
    cart_button.prop("disabled", true);
  } else {
    cart_button.prop("disabled", false);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="submit" data-product_id="1" data-product_sku="test" data-quantity="0" class="add_to_cart_button button product_type_simple">Add to cart</button><br><br>

<!-- Ignore code below this line, it's just for the demo -->

<button class="set_to_1">Set data-quantity to 1</button> <button class="set_to_0">Set data-quantity to 0</button>
```

EDIT: as you can see in the snippet above, your code is working perfectly fine. This is exactly how you can use such an if-statement, so good job!

Now, if it's still not working for you, make sure you have

1. jQuery initialized in your header
2. Wrapped the code in a `$(document).ready( function() {` your code `});`

If, then, it's still not working, you should open the console and refresh the page, and then post any errors that show up here. It could be some other part of your javascript (not displayed here) is breaking your code.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working fine for me;

jsfiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/y4jqp2vb/10/

```
$(function(){

    var cart_button = $('.add_to_cart_button');
    if(cart_button.attr("data-quantity") < 1) {
        cart_button.prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```

updated code to additional question, see same fiddle:

```
 $(function(){

    var cart_button = $('.add_to_cart_button');
    $('.add_to_cart_button').each(function(){
            if( $(this).attr("data-quantity") < 1) {
        $(this).prop("disabled", true);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

jQuery has built-in the ability to read (and set if need be) data tags.  [Use the `.data()` syntax](http://api.jquery.com/data/).  Note, that you drop the "data-" prefix when using this property.  Also, be sure you are wrapping everything in the `document.ready` function.

```
$(function(){
    var cart_button = $('.add_to_cart_button');
    if(cart_button.data("quantity") < 1) {
        cart_button.prop("disabled", true);
    }
});
```